# Flutter aggregate / add new item to an item list in PopupMenuButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `PopupMenuButton` in my chat application. I want to change my item list by tapping the *More* options item (Same as Whatsapp).

It seems that Whatsapp just closes the `PopupMenuButton` widget and opens a new one.

[image]
[image]

How do I close the current `PopupMenuButton` and opens a new one on tapping an item?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. I think you used **ExpansionTile** widget for your design go for documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html)

Your Widget:

```
   showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text(
                            'Choose Option',
                          ),
                          content: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                ListTile(
                                  title: Text('Your Text'),
                                ),
                                ListTile(
                                  title: Text('Your Text'),
                                ),
                                ListTile(
                                  title: Text('Your Text'),
                                ),
                                ExpansionTile(
                                  title: Text('ExpansionTile'),
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text('This is tile number 1'),
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text('This is tile number 2'),
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text('This is tile number 3'),
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text('This is tile number 4'),
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text('This is tile number 5'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
```

Your result screen Simple content -> [image]

Your result screen When you click expansion tile -> [image]

Comment: That does solve my issue (since I'm not using many items), but still it's not perfect as Whatsapp UX. Still looking for a Whatsapp like solution.