# how to design dialog box inside DropdownButtonFormField in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dropdownbutton, flutter-dialog

I have **DropdownButtonFormField** when I click on it a DialogBox with a list of items should appear, so I can select one item and it should return the selected item in DropdownButtonFormField.I tried with **DropdownMenuItem** but I need with DialogBox so that it looks good. **So basically I wanted to replace the DropdownMenuItem with DialogBox**. and I don't know how to do that I'm new to flutter, please help me with this. below I will attach images that I want to get.[image: reference images]

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Dialog Box and return value',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return MyHomePageState();
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      String  selectedLanguage =" ";
      var javascript ="java";
      var c = "C";
      var cpp = "C++";
      var python = "Python";
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold (
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Flutter SimpleDialog Example")
            ),
            body: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Center (
                  child: Column (
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          height: 50,
                          width: 150,
                          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                            items: [],
                            hint: Text("Select"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]
                  )
              ),
            )
        );
      }
    
      showMyAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    
        // Create SimpleDialog
        SimpleDialog dialog = SimpleDialog(
          title: const Text('Select a Language:'),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close and return value
                  Navigator.pop(context, javascript);
                },
                child: Text(javascript)
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                // Close and return value
                Navigator.pop(context, c);
              },
              child:  Text(c),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                // Close and return value
                Navigator.pop(context, cpp);
              },
              child:  Text(cpp),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                // Close and return value
                Navigator.pop(context, python);
              },
              child:  Text(python),
            )
          ],
        );
    
        // Call showDialog function to show dialog.
        Future futureValue = showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return dialog;
            }
        );
    
        futureValue.then( (language) => {
          this.setState(() {
            this.selectedLanguage = language;
          })
        });
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Is that right `^`  on second image, will be marked as selected item?

Comment: try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69567744/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Comment: Hey @YeasinSheikh I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689003/how-to-get-values-from-one-class-screen-to-another-class-and-populate-those-valu) could you please look into that and It will helpful for me. ThankYou in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included some comment that can help you to understand the concept I've applied.

```dart
void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: MyApp(),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dialog Box and return value',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? selectedLanguage;

  List<String> languages = ["java", "C", "C++", "Python"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Flutter SimpleDialog Example")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 50,
              width: 150,
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () async {
                    showMyAlertDialog(context);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text("${selectedLanguage ?? 'Select'}   "),
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                  //  DropdownButtonFormField(
                  //   items: [],
                  //   hint: Text("Select"),
                  // ),
                  ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  showMyAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: StatefulBuilder(
            //* dialog is on different widget Tree. check dev-tools
            builder: (context, setStateD) {
              return Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text("Language"),
                  const SizedBox(width: 12),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ...List.generate(
                        languages.length,
                        (index) => item(
                          text: languages[index], //sent String
                          isSelected: languages[index] ==
                              selectedLanguage, //check it is selected or not
                          ontap: () {
                            /// for inner dialog changes
                            setStateD(() {
                              selectedLanguage = languages[index];
                            });
                            Navigator.of(context)
                                .pop(); // if you wish to close the dilog on Select

                            setState(() {
                              //* for class state changes
                              selectedLanguage = languages[index];
                            });
                            print(selectedLanguage);
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget item(
      {required String text,
      required bool isSelected,
      required Function ontap}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: 4,
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () => ontap(),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(text),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            if (isSelected)
              const Icon(Icons
                  .check), // show only check while it is selected, or you can use the same logic on Main row item
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```